# Netflix Zuul (expose via https)

Tags: netflix-zuul

How do we expose Zuul with SSL certificates(say same cert...exposed via multiple DNS names).

Basically equivalent of below in Zuul.

Currently we have all our applications exposed via apache httpd proxy with the below setup for exposing services via SSL

ServerName XXX.com
        SSLEngine on
        #SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        #SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
        SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!LOW:!3DES:!PSK:!MD5:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

```
    SSLCertificateFile <cerfile>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile <pemfile>


    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
```

Thanks
Bharath